# Disk usage increased significantly after MacOS upgrade

Tags: macos, disk-space

My Mac has a 1TB drive. My disk usage was around 900GB. I used the GrandPerspective app to scan my drive to see what was taking up so much space. It helped me find a bunch of files to delete, which I did, but I still had about 400GB (!) of "Miscellaneous Used Space". I eventually figured out that it was local TimeMachine backups using that space. I turned off Automatic Time Machine backups in settings, and then deleted the local snapshots using `sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots` and reclaimed that space to get my usage down to 500GB.

But then I did a software update (Big Sur bug fix release) and suddenly an extra 170GB was being used. Presumably these are some temporary files from the update. But where are they? And how can I remove them? Thanks!

Comment: They are probably new snapshots, and therefore nothing to worry about. The space will be recovered if needed. An OS installer is only 5 Gb or so.

Comment: Thanks benwiggy, this is what I figured. Do you know where they are stored and how to purge them if needed?

Comment: They are a part of the filesystem, and not 'stored files' as such. Normally, you should not need to purge them: they are only stored for 24 hours, as part of your TM backups (which of course you should be making). If the OS needs the space, it will delete them itself.  In my experience, leaving things alone is usually the best policy. 400Gb does seem excessive for one day, as it's usually a delta, like TM. If you turn off TM, then it actually saves more backups to the disk, so turn TM back on for starters.

Comment: It will all flush through next couple of times Time Machine runs to its regular external disk. At the moment it's trying to keep a whole slew of changes locally. You can't switch the local storage off, so re-enabling external & letting it run will be more beneficial than trying to micro-manage it yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight. The reason I'm being fussy about this is that I'm buying a new machine, and trying to figure out if I can get away with 1TB again, or need to jump to 2TB. So I need to get a handle on how much of the disk usage is my stuff, how much is used by the system, what is ephemeral, what is permanent, etc.